# Error while fetching git file using Bundler

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "nokogiri", :git => "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git"
```

When I run `bundle`, the following error occurs:

```
Fetching git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/source.rb:592:in ``': No such file or directory - git clone "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git" "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/nokogiri-d4bf05cb9e65f144f074351e5ebe3a0e44c00952" --bare --no-hardlinks (Errno::ENOENT)
```

How can I solve it?

It's reproducible not only with this gem but also with other gems: cucumber, capybara

I use Windows.

Comment: Is the `git` command working in general? Does `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/` exist?

Comment: @iltempo folder C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/ exists but it's empty

Comment: See https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2044 for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was because I didn't have Git installed.

I installed Git and added it into PATH system variable. `bundle` became to work after that

Answer (score 1):

For any other newbies out there, I installed Git on Windows 7 with [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/).

Then in the `msysgit` command window (`MINGW32`) I moved to my rails project directory and ran bundle install and it worked fine.

Thanks for helping me with this Andrey.